# Creating iterator for conainter and friend class doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates

i wrote container template class Slist with all function. Class Slist inherit from abstract class Container so :
In Slist class (on the end of declarations) :

```
friend class Iterator<T>;
```

In Iterator class (on the begin of declarations):

```
friend class Slist<T>;
```

But when i'm trying to get access to private members of class(for example):

```
Slist<T>::head;
```

I'm getting :

```
 : access declaration can only be applied to a base class member
error C2602: 'Slist<T>::head' is not a member of a base class of 'Iterator<T>'
```

What's wrong?

EDIT------------
I understand but in Slist class i have node creating as `struct node{...}` for example if i would like to create iterator as pointer to list elements i cant do this by S`list<T>::node * pointer`; Why not? How to solve this?
I'm getting :

```
Slist<T>::node' : dependent name is not a type
```

Comment: `Slist` is still a separate class, not a base class. So unless `head` is a static member that will not work. You need an *instance* of `Slist` in order to access `head` (i.e `x.head`).

Comment: I added one more question

Comment: `But when i'm trying to get access to private members` How exactly are you "trying to get access"? Show the actual code that triggers the error. The error message suggests you are trying to write `using SList<T>::head`. This makes no sense.

Comment: Make it `typename Slist<T>::node`. For explanation, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: Like I said: `typename Slist<T>::node* pointer;`. You may want to introduce a typedef for `typename Slist<T>::node`, for less typing.